# How can one start Activity Monitor with a specific Dock icon?

Tags: dock, icon, activity-monitor, sonoma

I saw how one can start multiple instances of Activity Monitor using `open -na "Activity Monitor"`, but then one has to select the Dock Icon view for each separately; is there a way to start an instance with a specific Dock Icon view?

If there are three instances of Activity Monitor running *(I'm on Sonoma)*, each with a different Dock view, after a restart they don't keep their separate instances+Dock-Icon-view.  I suspect I'd have to make a script to start up the 3 instances, but I don't know how to specify the "Dock Icon" view.

Comment: Why do you need three instances of AM? Is it to see e.g. CPU, Memory and Disk all at the same time? There might be easier ways of doing that.

Comment: It seems cleaner to glance at the dock icons rather than have the full AM window open taking up real-estate on the screen -- to get a quick view of what might be the source of unexpected sluggish responsiveness.  When transferring files in the background, the Network activity is a nice way to quickly notice whether it is completed or still progressing normally.

Comment: You might want to consider [iStatMenus](https://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/) to provide the data you want to monitor.   [MenuMeters](https://member.ipmu.jp/yuji.tachikawa/MenuMetersElCapitan/) is an older product with may still work.  _Disclaimer_: Not affiliated with Bjango® Pty Ltd.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers to menu-bar alternatives; of course, one advantage of Dock Icons is that (with Magnify enabled) one can quickly check a somewhat larger view of the graph of interest.  FYI: I also use Memory Monitor; while it doesn't show "pressure", it does overlay Page-In/Out activity, which is another useful indicator of what's going on. (https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/21449/memory-monitor)

Comment: I guess I'm also curious about how one might find out about possible arguments to an Apple app such as AM.

Comment: Prefs will be held in ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.ActivityMonitor.plist - but you'd need to modify it as each instance launches, as they'll all be reading from the same file.

Comment: I'm curious about what problems you're experiencing that need this level of manual scrutiny.

Comment: re: 'problems'.  Nothing chronic; the smoother & quicker things run normally, my inquisitive mind is always curious as to what might be going on even with the occasional hiccup or sluggishness. "Hmmm; browser's a little less responsive at the moment... oh, network & disk I/O just bumped up a bit -- oh, backup just started."  The patterns of data when things are "normal" are helpful toward diagnosing when things are different than "normal".